# datetime.date no tiene el parametro fromisoformat

Tags: python, linux

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente código desde mi terminal en Linux (lo obtuve desde la documentación oficial de python):

```
    >>> from datetime import date
    >>> date.fromisoformat('2019-12-04')
```

Y aparece el sigiente error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta disponible a partir de la version 3.7

Lo más probable es que tengas una versión anterior.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Nov 15 2019, 04:04:52)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.fromisoformat('2019-12-04')
datetime.date(2019, 12, 4)
```

Comment: Tienes razón, estaba en la versión 3.6.9, muchas gracias